# Установка sass на windows xp

Tags: windows, phpstorm, sass, установка

Доброго времени, подскажите пожалуйста, работает ли compass и sass на Windows XP и в конечном счёте PHPStorm 10, потому что на сайте об этом ни слова...? и я не хочу таскать свой комп...